# ColdFusion with ORM init function setting values in a none persistent property

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Why does this not work in ColdFusion with ORM? I don't get any error but getval2() is blank

```
property name="ID"  type="string"    fieldtype="id" generator="guid";
property name="val1"    type="string"     ormtype="string"  persistent=true;

property name="val2"    type="any"      persistent=false    default="";

 public statsEntity function init(){

    variables.val2= this.getval1();

  return Super.init();
}
```

what I think should happen is getval2() should be the value of val1.

Any ideas why this is not the case?

ORMExecuteQuery("from myTable")

Comment: What's the value of `val1` at the time the object is loaded?

Comment: val1 one if I dump = "test" strange thing is if i do...  variables.val2= this I get all the entity i.e ID, Val1. so the stuct "this" does have everything in it. maybe I need to access it like this[1].val1?

Comment: event stranger, if i do writeDump(variables); abort; in the init() function I get everything in 'entity' like it has been created for the first time then I get a error at the end of the dump [empty string]. I don't think CF init() this at all when using ORMExecuteQuery("from myTable") even tried ORMExecuteQuery("from myTable").init() no error but the same result. The only thing I can see is anything in default="" which looks to me like it only creates the object does not update its values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly, but init() only runs on new enitity so will NOT work here try postLoad() not init().

Comment: cool this worked! Thanks I created a new function and added variables.val2= variables.val1 and it worked

Comment: Event Handlers for ORM: http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/introducing-the-coldfusion-9-orm-event-handler-216

Comment: note for future people: you must explicitly enable event handlers in your orm config. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1690-Learning-ColdFusion-9-Trying-To-Understand-ORM-Event-Handling.htm